# How regular expression handles `^` or `$` in the middle of regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex, re-python

I am trying to play with regular expressions in python. I have framed regular expression as given below. I know that `^` is used to match at the beginning of search string. I have framed by match pattern which contains multiple `^`, but I am not sure about how `re` will try to match the pattern in search string.

```
re.match("^def/^def", "def/def")
```

I was expecting that `re` will be raising error, regarding invalid regular expression, but it doesn't raise any error and returns no matches.

So, my questions is `"^def/^def"` or `"$def/$def"` a valid regular expression ?

Comment: Doesn't your experiment demonstrate that the answer is "yes"? Note that those characters can also refer to the start and end of *lines*, in multiline mode.

Comment: Actually you can create lots of nonsense regular expressions.   Putting "start of input" (`^`) in the middle is just one of many possibilities.  Another would be sth like `()*` (empty string repeated any number of times).  Some nonsense-patterns are found and complained about (e. g. `a{6,3}`, `a**`), others are silently accepted and will either match anything or nothing, depending on their nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have an invalid regular expression, `^` has legal uses in the middle of a string. When you use the [`re.M` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M) for example:

> When specified, the pattern character `'^'` matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character `'$'` matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline).

It is also possible to create patterns with optional groups, where a later `^` would still match if all of the preceding pattern matched the empty string. Using the `^` in places it can't match is not something the parser checks for and no error will be raised.

Your specific pattern will never match anything, because the `^` in the middle is unconditional and there is no possibility that the `/` preceding it will ever match the requisite newline character, even if the multiline flag was enabled.

Comment: Thanks Sir for such detailed information. Can you please let me know, about the cases, where it's possible to create optional groups and have ^ match the middle of string, which you have mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @ManguSinghRajpurohit; I meant that a pattern can have the `^` in the middle and still match. `r'[abc]*^start'` can match, for example, because the pattern before the `^` can match the empty string.